# ASP.NET MVC project building starts failing on travis-ci

Tags: c#, asp.net, build, travis-ci

Recently my ASP.NET project started failing on travis-ci. I have searched all over the internet and different forums but cant seem to find a solution. I am not a travis-ci genie but I do understand the basics.

Since a few days the builds started receiving the following error:

```
error MSB4044: The "KillProcess" task was not given a value for the required parameter "ImagePath".
```

[Image with the full error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIGhd.png)

I have tried to rebuild a previous commit that built successfully in the past. To test if I screwed something up with project files. Unfortunately that failed as well.

[The successful commit build log.](https://travis-ci.org/D4N3-777/DinWebsite/builds/301100498)

[The same commit failing now.](https://travis-ci.org/D4N3-777/DinWebsite/builds/321148499)

All answers are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Travis-Ci switched from xbuild to msbuild as default build platform. And currently the msbuild platform does not fully support standard .NET projects on UNIX based systems only .NET core.

So a temporary workaround is to reconfigure the travis.yml file to build with xbuild.

example:

```
language: csharp 
solution: {path to .sln} 
script: 
  - xbuild /p:Configuration=Release {path to .sln}
```

Comment: OK but how I do that?