# Visual Studio 2017 on Mac: The "KillProcess" task was not given a value for the required parameter "ImagePath" (MSB4044)

Tags: visual-studio-2017

My coworker just installed Visual Studio 2017 for Mac via this link: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/mac/. After everything was installed, he attempted to build the Asp.Net MVC C# project and got the following error:

[image]

Everyone else uses Windows, so we have never seen this problem before. However, I *think* I have found the root cause: DotNetCompilerPlatform.props's `WebProjectOutputDir` is null, but I haven't been able to verify this.

```
<KillProcess ProcessName="VBCSCompiler" ImagePath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
```

Is it possible to set `WebProjectOutputDir` manually, or at least view its value on Mac? Why is this an issue on Mac and not Windows?

I've looked around for other answers but didn't find them helpful/relevant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While it is possible to build a .NET core application on a Mac (because it is cross-platform), it is not possible to build a .NET framework application on Mac (because it is Windows-specific).

Therefore, my coworker should find a Windows machine for dev.

Comment: It is a shame. :( I was so hopefull when I see MAC version. There is a project type as ASP.Net Web App (MVC) in MAC version. So we should be able to run it. I looks like there is a bug and they haven't solved it yet. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/130218/the-killprocess-task-was-not-given-a-value-for-the.html

Answer (score 3):

May not be the best way, but the following process worked for me:

Click on the error to open the file: Microsoft.codeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props
In this file replace line no 20

```
<KillProcess ProcessName="VBCSCompiler" ImagePath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
```

with

```
<KillProcess ProcessName="VBCSCompiler" ImagePath="some right folder path in your local system" />
```

Comment: I created a directory C:\temp\RoslynTemp and worked.

Answer (score 1):

Mono goes a looooong way in running .Net code but there's quite a few gotchas. For this one, edit your csproj file and add this to one of the `<PropertyGroup>` sections:

```
<WebProjectOutputDir Condition="$(WebProjectOutputDir) == '' AND $(OS) == 'Unix' ">./</WebProjectOutputDir>
<!-- Hack for the fact that Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.8/build/net45/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props references $WebProjectOutputDir  -->
```

I have listed other gotchas in the link below

References

- https://www.cafe-encounter.net/p178/aspnet-macos-mono-visual-studio-jetbrains-rider
- https://www.cafe-encounter.net/p2312/multi-targetting-net-framework-and-net-core-in-a-single-project

Answer (score 0):

this answer resolved my issue
[ASP.NET MVC project building starts failing on travis-ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47964233/asp-net-mvc-project-building-starts-failing-on-travis-ci?rq=1)

Apparently Travis-Ci switched from xbuild to msbuild as default build platform. And currently the msbuild platform does not fully support standard .NET projects on UNIX based systems only .NET core.

So a temporary workaround is to reconfigure the project to build with xbuild.